# NullPointerException at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion.setRegion LIBGDX

Tags: button, input, nullpointerexception, libgdx

I am getting null pointer exception when I  try spawning an item(Mushroom) when the player  collides with a particular coin(As in MARIO game). I have been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8g44JssVmc&list=PLZm85UZQLd2SXQzsF-a0-pPF6IWDDdrXt&index=21) tutorial but I want the inputs to be buttons and not the keys. I have created 4 buttons and added to the stage . The inputs are working perfectly . But I am getting exception when,

I simply add the buttons to the stage and the input is still using keys

I am not getting exception when,

I remove all the buttons from the code and the input is using keys.

Here is my code for adding buttons to the stage ,

```
        public class PlayScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor

      {
      .......
     private Array<Item> items;                                             
     private LinkedBlockingQueue<ItemDef> itemsToSpawn; 
     private TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas("move_sprites.pack"); //contains the mushroom as well as the player packed together  


    public PlayScreen(MyGame game) {
           .............
    stage = new Stage();
    atlas = new TextureAtlas("ui/button_pack.pack");                                                                                                      
    skin = new Skin(atlas);
    white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/white.fnt"), false);
    black = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/black.fnt"), false);

    TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("buttonin");
    textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("buttonout");
    textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetX = 1;
    textButtonStyle.font = black;
    buttonright = new TextButton("Right", textButtonStyle);
    buttonleft = new TextButton("Left", textButtonStyle);
    //table.setBounds(500, 5, 250, 150);
    buttonleft.setPosition(350, 5);
    buttonleft.setHeight(100);
    buttonleft.setWidth(100);
    buttonright.setPosition(100, 5);
    buttonright.setHeight(100);
    buttonright.setWidth(100);

    buttonup = new TextButton("up", textButtonStyle);
    buttonup.setPosition(600, 5);
    buttonup.setHeight(100);
    buttonup.setWidth(100);
    stage.addActor(buttonup);
    stage.addActor(buttonright);
    stage.addActor(buttonleft);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        ......
}
```

//create a new method

```
  public void spawnItem(ItemDef idef)                                                       
 {
    itemsToSpawn.add(idef);
 }


public void handleSpawingItems()                                                 
    {
    if (!itemsToSpawn.isEmpty()) {                                               
        ItemDef idef = itemsToSpawn.poll();      //poll is pop                                
        if (idef.type == Mushroom.class) {                                       
            items.add(new Mushroom(this, idef.position.x, idef.position.y));     
        }
    }
}
  public void update(float dt) {                                                           

    handleInput(dt);                                                                      

    handleSpawingItems(); 
    ........
 }
```

//Giving inputs using buttons

```
   public void handleInput(float dt)
    {
    if (gamehero.currentState != Hero.State.DEAD) {

       buttonup.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

       gamehero.heroBody.setLinearVelocity(0, 4f);

                }
        return true;
          }
     }
        );
     }
}
public void render(float delta) 
     {
  ......
    update(delta); 
    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
       }
   }
}
```

Mushroom Class..

```
   public class Mushroom extends Item {
   public Mushroom(PlayScreen screen, float x, float y) {
    super(screen, x, y);
```

//mush is one of the sprite packed together using texture packer. Exception is thrown in the below line

```
    setRegion(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("mush"), 0, 0, 16, 16);      
    velocity = new Vector2(0.7f, 0); //velocity of mushroom             
}
```

I am triggering this mushroom when mario head collides with coin like below,

```
  public class Coins extends InteractiveTileObject {
  ....

   public void onHeadHit(Hero hero) {
    if (object.getProperties().containsKey("mushroom"))       {
        Gdx.app.log("coins", "collision");
```

//Exception occurs in the below line too. When the collision occurs, spawnItem method is called in the main class

```
        screen.spawnItem(new ItemDef(new Vector2(body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y + 16 / MyGame.PPM), Mushroom.class));     
    }
```

ItemDef Class,

```
public class ItemDef {
public Vector2 position;           
public Class<?> type;                

public ItemDef(Vector2 position, Class<?> type)            
     {
    this.position = position;                      
    this.type = type;                                
    }
```

}

Exception occurs if I just add a button to my code and gave the input using keys. Problem lies in spawning the mushroom if I just add a button to my code. Its weird. Please help. I am a beginner . Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your `public void update` method executed in a render loop of your game? If so, you shouldn't add new input listener here, but right after button's initialization.

Comment: `mush` probably does not exist in your atlas. Or the atlas returned from `screen.getAtlas()` is still null at that point. Place a breakpoint on that line and investigate what actually is null. Then simply fix that by making sure you initialize it properly. Your controls have nothing to do with your atlas being, please ask clear and specific questions.

Comment: If the screen.getAtlas( ) is null then how will it execute without any exception if I remove the buttons and give the inputs using keys @ Menno Gouw

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause for this Exception.
I have given the same name for 2 TextureAtlas while declaring,

```
 private TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas("move_sprites.pack");
```

and the other,

```
atlas = new TextureAtlas("ui/button_pack.pack");
```

But I am referring the first TextureAtlas in other class. Since I have declared the TextureAtlas only once but used for two different packs, It threw null pointer exception as there was name conflict. Thanks for all your answers.